# How to build a list recursively given only the length?

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function that takes a number n and some value, let's say `'a'`, and recursively builds a list made up of `n` `'a'`s.

So, `func(4, 'a')` returns `['a','a','a','a']`.

My internet searches so far have been surprisingly futile.  Most examples of list recursion I have found take additional parameters.

I have tried various versions of the following code:

```py
def func(n, a):
    if n == 1:
        return [a]
    else:
        return func(n-1, a).append(a)
```

I keep getting `cannot append to NoneType` errors on that last return.  So `func(n-1,a)` is returning `None`.

Comment: Because `.append` returns `None` and so will your else branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `list.append` method returns `None` you have to do it this way if you want to use the `append` method:

```
def func(n, a):
    if n == 1:
        return [a]
    else:
        temp = func(n-1, a)
        temp.append(a)
        return temp

print(func(5, 'a'))
```

Prints:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

Answer (score 2):

`list.append` only returns `None` as its purpose is to update the target list in-place. Instead of appending, simply add:

```
def func(n, a):
   if n == 1:
      return [a]
   else:
      return func(n-1, a) + [a]

print(func(4, 'a'))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

Additionally, you may want to consider using generators to provide a cleaner (and shorter) result:

```
def func(n, a):
  if n:
    yield a
    yield from func(n-1, a)

print(list(func(4, 'a')))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

Comment: Good answer. Note that you could shorten the [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators) version to simply `yield from (a for _ in range(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be recursive?

def func(n, a):
    a_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        a_list.append(str(a))
    return a_list